# How to create empty clone directories using bash script as subdirectories under another directory

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create empty clone directories with the same directory names as subdirectories under another directory in another location, I need to accomplish this using bash scripting.

To be  more specific, I have a number of directories that are being generated by a data logging system with each directory being named according to the day, month, and, year of creation/recording, hence I have a starting directory say 24012016 and so on with increments in the day number, month, and, year; also there are gaps in records for certain days due to technical reasons.

Each such directory contains files with two different extensions; I need a script that will create a directory with the same name, that is 24012016, as a subdirectory under another directory in another location, but without the files within it, and, also copy files, one of the two with different extensions into the new clone directory, have this process repeated for all the directories, have this process repeated for all the directories.

Comment: You can use `find` tool with `exec` parameter.

Comment: You will regret not using natural date order. YYYYmmDD dates would be so much easier to work with in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

given `old_root` the base directory to start coping and `new_root` the base destination:

```
find <old_root> -type d -exec mkdir -p "<new_root>/{}" \;
```

the second part is unclear

Answer (score 0):

For example, something like that:

```
cd ${where_to_search}
find . -type d | while read dir; do
mkdir -p ${new_parentdir}/${dir}
done

find . -type f -name "*.${extension_to_copy}" | while read file; do
cp ${file} ${new_parent}/${file}; 
done
```